# Django Model reference assignment in loop

Tags: python, django

Is the following code correct? The `e` should refer to  a new object in the beginning of each for iteration, after try/except blocks are executed. I suspect some interference with an old object, because there is a bug which I cannot reproduce now.

```
 from webapp.models import Profile

....
    for e in Profile.objects.all():
        if not e.profile_link in profile_data:
            e.delete()

    try:
        for key, employee in profile_data.iteritems():
            #e still holds old reference
            try:
                #edit DB object if exists
                e = Profile.objects.all().filter(profile_link=key)[0]
            except Exception:
                #or create a new one
                e = Profile(profile_link=key)

            #modify e using employee

            e.save()
    except Exception:
        #handle exception
```

Comment: Do you mean to have the try/except block indented outside of the for loop?

Comment: Not good to have undefined Exception.  Let it fail, the learn what exceptions happen, and handle those

Comment: Probably there is no bug. You were supposed to make a function call `e.save()` instead of `e.save`

Comment: Just a suggestion rather than using `.all().filter()` try to change it to `.get(profile_link=key)`1 if this object doesn't exist, you are catching the `Exeception`. Just to increase a little bit of your performance

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the try/catch blocks to run within the for loop you need make sure your identation is correct

Try (check the indentation)

```
from webapp.models import Profile

....
for e in Profile.objects.all():
    if not e.profile_link in profile_data:
        e.delete()
    try:
        for key, employee in profile_data.iteritems():
            #e still holds old reference
            try:
                #edit DB object if exists
                e = Profile.objects.get(profile_link=key)
            except Exception:
                #or create a new one
                e = Profile(profile_link=key)

            #modify e using employee

            e.save()
    except Exception:
        #handle exception
```